# How to Install a version 7 update 76 of java in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, jdk

I installed the jdk7u80 the oracle and I wonder what I should do to completely remove it and install the jdk7u76 the oracle?

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done like this:

Remove the link:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk[version]/bin/java"

sudo update-alternatives --remove "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk[version]/bin/javac"

sudo update-alternatives --remove "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk[version]/bin/javaws"
```

Then, remove the package in the /usr/lib/jvm

```
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/jdk[version]
```

**Note :**

Change [version] with any version number that's contained in jdk folder's name,     example : jdk[version] = jdk1.7.0_13

**For installation specific java file:**

1. Download it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jre-7u76-oth-JPR).
2. Optional (if you are not logged as root you need)

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
3. Untar the package `tar -zxf jdk-7u76-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk`
4. Set Oracle's Java as default

   ```
   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java  /opt/jdk/[version]/bin/java 100
   ```

   `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/[version]/bin/javac 100`
5. Check Java version if it is ok

   ```
   java -version
   ```